# ggplot2 legend to bottom and horizontal

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I move a `ggplot2` legend to the bottom of the plot and turn it horizontally?

**Sample code:**

```
library(reshape2) # for melt
df <- melt(outer(1:4, 1:4), varnames = c("X1", "X2"))
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value))
p1 + scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend())
```

**Desired (approximate) outcome:**
[image]

Comment: After 7 years and 8 months, I finally figured out how to get the desired outcome for this question :) Scroll down to the second answer.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

If you want to move the position of the legend please use the following code:

```
library(reshape2) # for melt
df <- melt(outer(1:4, 1:4), varnames = c("X1", "X2"))
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value))
p1 + scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend()) +
    theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

This should give you the desired result. 
[image: Legend at bottom]

Comment: do you know if it possible to draw a continuous legend bar on the bottom? (so not with the number in between but on top). thanks.

Comment: With current `ggplot`, this gives me the warning `'opts' is deprecated. Use 'theme' instead. (Deprecated; last used in version 0.9.1)`. Replacing `opts` by `theme` works.

Comment: Yes I anticipate there is change in the internal workings of `ggplot`

Comment: It is bad practice to use depreciated items. You can do it using theme the exact same way: `+ theme(legend.position='bottom')`

Comment: unfortunately there is some ambiguity when the numbers and colors are side-by-side; see my answer below at several attempts to improve on this.

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883294/increasing-whitespace-between-legend-items-in-ggplot2/50885122#50885122 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401568/r-ggplot-add-space-between-legend-items https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780836/spacing-between-legend-keys-in-ggplot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402427/space-between-gpplot2-horizontal-legend-elements to avoid the spacing problem.

Answer (score 61):

Here is how to create the desired outcome:

```r
library(reshape2); library(tidyverse)
melt(outer(1:4, 1:4), varnames = c("X1", "X2")) %>%
ggplot() + 
  geom_tile(aes(X1, X2, fill = value)) + 
  scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend()) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        legend.spacing.x = unit(0, 'cm'))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(label.position = "bottom"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

Edit: no need for these imperfect options anymore, but I'm leaving them here for reference.

Two imperfect options that don't give you exactly what you were asking for, but pretty close (will at least put the colours together).

```r
library(reshape2); library(tidyverse)
df <- melt(outer(1:4, 1:4), varnames = c("X1", "X2"))
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value))
p1 + scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend()) +
 theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.direction="vertical")
```

[image]

```r
p1 + scale_fill_continuous(guide = "colorbar") + theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>