# Increasing whitespace between legend items in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

My question is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366964/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-spacing-between-legend-items-in-ggplot2). Note that I'm using version 2.3.0 which is available on [github](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2), not yet on CRAN.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame("Categories" = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 3),  
                 "values" = c(rep(0.39, 3), rep(0.37, 3), rep(0.24, 3)),
                 "X" = 1:9)

ggplot(df, aes(x = X, y = values, colour = Categories)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme(
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.spacing.x = unit(2, unit = "cm"),
        legend.title = element_blank()
        )
```

The code above creates this plot.

[image]

I would like to move the legend labels (A, B, C) closer to their corresponding icons, as shown by the red arrows below, which would create more whitespace between the legend categories. How would I do that?

[image]

Comment: Can you not reduce `legend.spacing.x`?

Comment: `legend.text.align =  unit(-1, unit = "cm")` - help page suggest it take a number but doesnt seem to work unless a unit

Comment: @Tung the point of the question is to increase the whitespace in between the legend keys.

Comment: @user2957945 Tried that - didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible workaround is to add extra whitespace on the right of `Categories` using [`stringr::str_pad`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html)

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame("Categories" = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 3),  
                 "values" = c(rep(0.39, 3), rep(0.37, 3), rep(0.24, 3)),
                 "X" = 1:9)

# define a custom function
str_pad_custom <- function(labels){
  new_labels <- stringr::str_pad(labels, 10, "right")
  return(new_labels)
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = X, y = values, colour = Categories)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_brewer(labels  = str_pad_custom,
                     palette = "Dark2") +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.key.width = unit(1.0,  unit = "cm"),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.25, unit = "cm"),
    legend.title = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-06-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).</sup>