# Adjusting space between legend text and boxes after coord_flip() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to move the legend text and legend boxes further apart (horizontally) on a box and jitter plot. The complicating factor is the `coord_flip` I used to make the boxplot horizontal. In `theme` I tried using both `legend.spacing.x` and `legend.spacing.y` but neither had any effect on the distance between legend text and legend boxes.

Here is the graph with fake data. More complex than necessary I know but I need to be able to make it work with all the complications.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(01234)

# make some data
totDays <- data.frame(id = 1:80,
                      group = rep(c("Placebo", "Drug"), each = 40),
                      total84 = c(pmin(abs(round(rnorm(40, 55, 30))),84), pmin(abs(round(rnorm(40, 38, 30))),84)))


# get some descriptives
(groupDF <- totDays %>% group_by(group) %>%
                        dplyr::summarise(m = mean(total84, na.rm = T),
                                         sd = sd(total84, na.rm = T),
                                         count = n()) %>%
                        mutate(se = sd/sqrt(count)))

# now for the box and scatter plot
(g <- ggplot(totDays, aes(group, total84, colour = group)) +
              geom_jitter(size = 1, width = 0.1) + # so points aren't overlaid, width controls how much jitter
              geom_point(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", shape = 3, size = 3, colour = "black") + # crosses for mean
              geom_boxplot(alpha = 0, width = 0.5, lwd = 1, size = 0.5) +
              scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) +
              scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,84,14), minor_breaks = seq(0, 84, 14)) + # changes minor break line
              coord_flip() +
              labs(y = "Score") +
              geom_hline(yintercept = c(groupDF$m), linetype = "dotted") +
              geom_segment(x = 2.38, xend = 2.38, y = groupDF$m[2] + .1, yend = groupDF$m[1] - .1, size = .7, arrow = arrow(end = "both", type = "open", length = unit(0.15, "cm")), colour = "#696969") +
              annotate("text", x = 2.46, y = mean(groupDF$m), label = paste0("italic(p) == ", 0.02), parse = T) +
              theme_bw() +
              theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13),
                    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13, face = "bold", margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 10, l = 0), vjust = -2), # note the use of margin to move the title away from the axis text
                    legend.title = element_blank(),
                    legend.position = "top",
                    legend.spacing.y = unit(.1, "cm"),
                    legend.box.spacing = unit(.1, "cm"), # adjusts distance of box from x-axis
                    legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"),
                    legend.text = element_text(size = 13, face = "bold"),
                    strip.text = element_text(size = 13, face = "bold"),
                    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
                    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(size=.4, color="#F7F7F7")))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the current plot?

Comment: See if these work for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/50615868/ & https://stackoverflow.com/a/50885122/

Comment: Thanks @Tung. I have posted the plot. I used the first of your referred posts to create the existing graphs but can't seem to get around the `coord_flip()` problem.

Comment: Can you include an illustration of what your desired outcome would look like? Going by your description, it sounds like adding `legend.spacing.x = unit([some positive number], "cm")` gives that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `stringr::str_pad()` or `theme(legend.spacing.x = ...)` or both

```r
g <- ggplot(totDays, aes(group, total84, colour = group)) +
    geom_jitter(size = 1, width = 0.1) + # so points aren't overlaid, width controls how much jitter
    geom_point(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", shape = 3, size = 3, colour = "black") + # crosses for mean
    geom_boxplot(alpha = 0, width = 0.5, lwd = 1, size = 0.5) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),

                       ### added
                       labels = stringr::str_pad(c("Drug", "Placebo"), 10, "right")) +

    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,84,14), minor_breaks = seq(0, 84, 14)) + # changes minor break line
    coord_flip() +
    labs(y = "Score") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = c(groupDF$m), linetype = "dotted") +
    geom_segment(x = 2.38, xend = 2.38, y = groupDF$m[2] + .1, yend = groupDF$m[1] - .1, size = .7, 
                 arrow = arrow(end = "both", type = "open", length = unit(0.15, "cm")), colour = "#696969") +
    annotate("text", x = 2.46, y = mean(groupDF$m), label = paste0("italic(p) == ", 0.02), parse = T) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13, face = "bold", 
                                      margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 10, l = 0), vjust = -2), 
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "top",

          ### added
          legend.spacing.x = unit(0.25, 'cm'),

          legend.spacing.y = unit(.1, "cm"),
          legend.box.spacing = unit(.1, "cm"), # adjusts distance of box from x-axis
          legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 13, face = "bold"),
          strip.text = element_text(size = 13, face = "bold"),
          panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.x = element_line(size=.4, color="#F7F7F7"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: @llewmills: `legend.spacing.x` will change the space between the box and the text within one legend key. Whereas, `str_pad()` will add more space between two or more legend keys

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @Tung. I will comment my script accordingly.