# Align legend horizontal ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggnewscale

I am curious as to whether there is a way to stack legends horizontally rather than vertically in `ggplot2` and `ggnewscale:`

Example using *mtcars* dataset:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = gear)) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(aes(col = carb))
```

Plot for example

[image]

Comment: Maybe this is useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032513/ggplot2-legend-to-bottom-and-horizontal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can individually control legends via `guides(...):`

```
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = gear)) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(aes(col = carb))+
  theme(legend.direction = "vertical",
      legend.box = "horizontal",
      legend.position = "right") +
  guides(size=guide_legend(direction='horizontal'))
```

[image]