# How to change orientation of each item in a ggplot2 legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

[image]

[image]

The above shows 2 legends, one where each item is placed in a new column and one where each item is placed in a new row.

How can I control for that?

Comment: Do you mean you want two legends in two different directions? Perhaps a simple reproducible example would be helpful here.

Comment: no, I want them both in the same direction

Comment: Can you show us the code that produces the two different legends in a single plot? They normally _do_ go in the same direction, so some data and code that reproduces the problem would be helpful here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 legend to bottom and horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032513/ggplot2-legend-to-bottom-and-horizontal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by the `nrow` and `ncol` arguments to `guide_legend()`.

You can call `guide_legend()` either within `guides()`:

```
plot + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 1))
```

…or within `scale_*()`:

```
plot +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_legend(nrow = 1))
```